# PostgreSQL conditional join and result filtering

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

**WHAT I WANT**

the name of *cast members who have starred in more than one of the same
director’s movies* (but *not directed by themselves*) and *directed at least one movie themselves*.

```
select * from moviesdirectors LIMIT 5
```

**Top 5 movie directors row**

```
movieid   director
6       Bob Persichetti
6       Peter Ramsey
6       Rodney Rothman
16      Sergio Leone
20      Spike Jonze
```

AND

```
select * from moviescast LIMIT 5
```

**Top 5 movie moviescast row**

```
movieid castname
427     Quei Tann
2878    Indrans
3272    Togo Igawa
517     Ajay Naidu
1608    Megan Sousa
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

```
select * from moviescast LEFT JOIN moviesdirectors ON moviesdirectors.movieid=moviescast.movieid
where castname in (select director from moviesdirectors) AND castname!=director 
ORDER BY castname
```

Comment: Rather than showing us the output from the wrong queries, you should instead include original sample data for all tables, then show the output you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sir, may I need to put all the rows of both of the tables? the results are exact from both of the two select queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to count people on the cast that:

1. directed one or more movies
2. have stared in more than one movie for the same director, but the movie shouldn't show them as co-directors.

If that is the case I replicated a similar dataset to yours with

```
create table moviesdirectors( movieid int, director varchar);
 create table moviescast( movieid int, castname varchar);
 
 insert into moviesdirectors values(6, 'Bob Persichetti');
 insert into moviesdirectors values(6, 'Peter Ramsey');
 insert into moviesdirectors values(6, 'Rodney Rothman');
 insert into moviesdirectors values(10, 'Sergio Leone');
 insert into moviesdirectors values(10, 'Spike Jonze');
 insert into moviesdirectors values(20, 'Spike Jonze');

 insert into moviescast values(6, 'Bob Persichetti');
 insert into moviescast values(20, 'Bob Persichetti');
 insert into moviescast values(10, 'Bob Persichetti');
 insert into moviescast values(6, 'Quei Tann');
 insert into moviescast values(20, 'Quei Tann');
 insert into moviescast values(10, 'Quei Tann');
 insert into moviescast values(6, 'Sergio Leone');
 insert into moviescast values(20, 'Sergio Leone');
 insert into moviescast values(6, 'Peter Ramsey');
 insert into moviescast values(20, 'Peter Ramsey');
```

The table `moviesdirectors` now contains the following

```
 movieid |    director     
---------+-----------------
       6 | Bob Persichetti
       6 | Peter Ramsey
       6 | Rodney Rothman
      10 | Sergio Leone
      10 | Spike Jonze
      20 | Spike Jonze
(6 rows)
```

and the table `moviescast` the following

```
 movieid |    castname     
---------+-----------------
       6 | Bob Persichetti
      20 | Bob Persichetti
      10 | Bob Persichetti
       6 | Quei Tann
      20 | Quei Tann
      10 | Quei Tann
       6 | Sergio Leone
      20 | Sergio Leone
       6 | Peter Ramsey
      20 | Peter Ramsey
(10 rows)
```

In the above dataset only `Bob Persichetti` working for `Spike Jonze` should satisfy the 2 conditions stated initially.

All the rest shouldn't since:

- `Quei Tann` never directed
- `Sergio Leone` casted in two movies but they were directed by different people
- `Peter Ramsey` casted in two movies but one (`movieid=6` was directed by himself too)

In order to provide the solution I split the problems in various steps in the following query:

1. `directed_by_themselves`: retrieves the list of `movieid`s where the `director` is also part of the cast
2. `directors`: retrieves the distinct list of directors
3. the last query glues everything up and removes from the resulting dataset all movies where an actor is also part of the directors

```
with directed_by_themselves as (
  select distinct moviesdirectors.movieid, 
         moviesdirectors.director 
  from moviesdirectors join moviescast 
  on moviesdirectors.movieid = moviescast.movieid 
  and moviesdirectors.director = moviescast.castname
 ),
 directors as (
 select distinct director from moviesdirectors) 
 
 select d.director, c.castname, count(*) nr_movies 
 from moviesdirectors d join moviescast c
 on (d.movieid = c.movieid)
 join directors dir on c.castname = dir.director
 where (d.movieid,c.castname) not in (select movieid,director from directed_by_themselves)
 group by d.director, c.castname
 having count(*) > 1;
```

the result is

```
  director   |    castname     | nr_movies 
-------------+-----------------+-----------
 Spike Jonze | Bob Persichetti |         2
(1 row)
```

Comment: sir, You guys are awesome, that's why I really like this platform. will accept your answer after some more test with my real dataset.